# When I running gh-rdf3x engine's commend rdf3xquery It prompt:parse error: unknown prefix 'http'

Tags: sparql, rdf

I try to use gh-rdf3x engine to do some SPARQL search, so I use LUBM-100 dataset and then I use RDF2RDF tool to make all .owl file into a test.nt file.
then I use gh-rdf3x command

```
./rdf3xload dataDB test.nt
```

to build a dataDB file. At last, I want to do some search so I use LUBM SPARQL#1 as `test.sparql`.

Then I do the command

```
./rdf3xquery dataDB test.sparql
```

It prompts

```
parse error: unknown prefix 'http'
```

I do all the thing as described in the [GH-RDF3X Wiki](https://github.com/gh-rdf3x/gh-rdf3x/wiki), so I don't know why it prompt that.
And the message may be from file `gh-rdf3x/cts/parser/TurtleParser.cpp`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: show the SPARQL query string contained in the file ... obviously, there must be a syntax error, thus, the parser fails. Note, non-prefixed URIs must by wrapped in `<` and `>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're using the LUBM query from [this file](http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/projects/lubm/queries-sparql.txt) which unfortunately contains several syntax errors.

The first query is missing the angle brackets `<` and `>` which must be put around full URIs:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ub: <http://www.lehigh.edu/~zhp2/2004/0401/univ-bench.owl#>
SELECT ?X WHERE {
  ?X rdf:type ub:GraduateStudent .
  ?X ub:takesCourse <http://www.Department0.University0.edu/GraduateCourse0>
}
```

Comment: And I have another problem. I use LUBM query like this 'select ?x ?y where{....}' It prompt 'parse error: 'where' expected', but this query already have 'where' and all it's URLs hava < and >. It seems that if more than one variables been selected, it prompt like what I said.

Comment: Which query is it in the file? Note, the commas between the variables are basically also not property SPARQL. I don't know who created he file

Comment: It seems that every LUBM query have different problems......orz. Thank you for your help again.